# Does anyone recognize this error message pop up in Salesforce?

Tags: unit-test, error, gack

I'm trying to run some tests in the Salesforce 'Apex Test Execution' page and suddenly this error message has popped up, it keeps appearing when I press the 'Select Tests...' button.

Has anyone seen it before? The numbers are constantly changing so I've no idea what they are.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a log associated with this error?

Comment: No I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem the other day and I had to contact Salesforce Support, and how I understood it was a error/exception that didn't get handled properly by the platform so it will be pretty much impossible to figure out which part of your code is throwing the error..

It appears there are some known issues located here.  I just skimmed through them but it might be worth a look..

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=Internal%20Error

Comment: Ok, cheers EricSSH